# Let $I$ be an ideal of a ring $R$, and let $S$ be a subring of $R$. Prove that $I\cap S$ is an ideal of $S$

Tags: ring-theory

Let $I$ be an ideal of a ring $R$, and let $S$ be a subring of $R$. Prove that $I\cap S$ is an ideal of $S$

I've tried listing the properties of an ideal, but I don't know where to go from there.

Comment: Multiply an element of $I\cap S$ with an element of $S$.  The product is clearly in $S$. (Why?)  Now to show the product is also in $I$ use the fact that $I$ is an ideal in $R$ and the element you chose from $S$ is clearly also in $R$.

Comment: It would have been awesome if you could have written down all the properties of ideal which property of ideal is bothering you...

Answer (score 2):

Let $J = I \cap S$.  Let $s_1, s_2 \in J$.  Then since $J = I \cap S \subset I$, $s_1, s_2 \in I$.  Thus, since $I$ is an ideal, $s_1 - s_2 \in I$; we also have $s_1, s_2 \in S$, whence
$s_1 - s_2 \in S$.  Thus $s_1 - s_2 \in I \cap S = J$.  Next, if $s \in J$ and $r \in S$, we have $s \in I$ whence $rs, sr \in I$, and the fact that $S$ is a subring means $rs, sr \in S$.
So $rs, sr \in I \cap S = J$, showing $J$ is a two-sided ideal of $S$ if $I$ is a two-sided ideal of $R$.  Scrutiny of these assertions reveals that similar conclusions hold if $I$ is a left or right ideal; $J$ inherits the "ideality" of $I$ in all cases.  ***QED***

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***